# Need help regarding Wildfly 9 SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, wildfly

I want to implement SSO between two apps that are deployed on same instance of Wildfly 9. I have searched about it but never got enough information regarding it.

First thing is we have to start from `standalone.xml`:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                <single-sign-on domain="localhost"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>
```

Then in `jboss-web.xml` put following entry of security-domain and valve:

```
<jboss-web> 
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
    <valve> 
        <class-name>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn</class-name> 
    </valve> 
</jboss-web>
```

I am not sure about changes in `web.xml`.

I think we have to provide information about security-constraint and login-config.

Please help me to implement this concept in both clustered and non-clustered environment.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the following line at `default-host` host under the `default-server` server:

```
<single-sign-on path="/"/>
```

At the end, it will be like:

```
<server name="default-server">
    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
        <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
        <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
        <single-sign-on path="/"/>
        </host>
</server>
```

I'm using **Wildfly 9.0.2 Final**.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn can't work on WildFly AS, because Tomcat is substituted by Undertow as a web container.
Normally, you don't need any change to jboss-web.xml.

For an IdP based on PicketLink, you can set jboss-web.xml as following to enable the PicketLink Authenticator:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>IDPFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.picketlink.identity.federation.web.filters.IDPFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>IDPFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I complete the "tiago mussi" answer, valve are note supported anymore on widlfy because it uses the new webserver undertow, you can put the valve line in jboss-web it will do nothing at all...

```
<single-sign-on domain="localhost"/>
```

this is bad syntax because there is a bug in domain sso

```
<single-sign-on path="/"/>
```

this is the right syntax then in your web application you will see JSESSIONSSOID or like this name in plus than SESSIONID

picketLink is too much just for use SSO, because it handle API REST SSO, social secure, and it is a specific module with a new mechanism authentication, and furthermore if you will manage several URL you can't because you have to put in configuration the url, it is not dynamic...